# My Keyboard Keeps Switching Languages

Tags: keyboard, language

I’ve had this problem for about 4-5 months now, my phone switches between Vietnamese and English. I only have English as a language for my input but it still switches to Vietnamese. I’ve added Vietnamese and removed it from the input to see if it would help but it hasn’t. No matter who I’m talking to, it changed between languages.

Comment: Which version of iOS are you running? What is shown in Settings->Keyboard->Keyboards?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "input".  The key thing is to have only one item, with the name English, on your list in Settings > General > Keyboard > Keyboards.  Remove any other language you have on that list.